# Collapse lines into a single line (separating the original lines with commas)

Tags: text-processing

I'm storing the results to a variable and results are represented as columns. And looking to convert to row with a coma in between as separator.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
echo $var

'2017-08-09'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
```

Result:

```
echo $var

'2017-08-09','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01'
```

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: updated post with results.

Answer (score 2):

With **`paste`** command:

```
var="$(paste -d',' -s <<<"$var")"
```

- `-d','` - merging lines of file using `,` as delimiter

Comment: What if want double quotes to the same variable. Should I have to use escape "?                                                   
 echo $var "'2017-08-09','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-0‌​1-01','2017-01-01','‌​2017-01-01','2017-01‌​-01','2017-01-01','2‌​017-01-01','2017-01-‌​01','2017-01-01'"

Comment: @Kiran, elaborate what double quotes you need: trailing double quotes OR surrounding double quotes for each item ?

Comment: I have to populate the whole result with double quotes

Comment: post how it should look

Answer (score 0):

With `tr` and a side order of `sed`:

```
$ cat in.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
input="$( echo "'2017-08-09'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'
'2017-01-01'" )"
echo "$input" | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'
$ ./in.sh
'2017-08-09','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01'
```